# Play a sound effect only while enemy is alive in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

I created a small 2d plane shooter game using pygame. I have few choppers as enemies. What i want is to play chopper sound as sound effect from the point chopper is generated to the point where its destroyed by the player. The sound effect should stop when the chopper gets destroyed. Now the issue i am facing is that sound effect is still plying even when the chopper is destroyed.

here's what i am doing

```
chopper_fx = pygame.mixer.Sound('Sounds/chopper.mp3')
# now when the chopper is generated at particular time
chopper_fx.play()
```

but i don't know how to stop this sound effect when the chopper gets destroyed

P.S. : I already have a background game music running in the background and multiple choppers will be generated throughout the game.

[You can download the code from here](https://github.com/pyGuru123/Python-Games/tree/master/Aeroblasters)

[image: still from my game]

Comment: `chopper_fx.stop()`?

Comment: it works when there's only one chopper on screen. In case of multiple choppers the sound effect entirely stops for all choppers. I want to stop it for the only chopper which gets destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

You can tie the sound effect to an object by adding it in its attribute and playing an instance of it when the object is created.

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, type_):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__()
        if type_ == 4 or type_ == 5:
            self.fx = pygame.mixer.Sound('Sounds/chopper.mp3')
        # rest of the code
        fx.play()
    # Stop the music when chopper is destroyed
    def update(self, enemy_bullet_group, explosion_group):
        self.rect.y += self.speed
        if self.rect.top >= HEIGHT:
            self.fx.stop()
            self.kill()

        if self.health <= 0:
            x, y = self.rect.center
            explosion = Explosion(x, y, 2)
            explosion_group.add(explosion)
            
            self.fx.stop()
            self.kill()
```